# Exception has occurred: TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, list, random, integer, sample

Trying to make a Basic Text Dungeon Game and was struck with the following error:

"Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'"

The following error is from this line: MonsterHealth = Monster_One_Health - Move_Chooser

```
import random, math, sys, os, os.path, time

#These Variables are for the Player's Move DMG
Slash = 3.1
Dash = 2.5
Slam = 5

vars = [Slash,Dash,Slam]

Move_Chooser = random.sample(vars, 1)

MonsterHealth = Monster_One_Health - Move_Chooser

    if vars == 2.5:
        print("Player Has Used Dash Attack")
        print("Monster[1] has taken 2.5 Hearts of DMG")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(MonsterHealth)

    elif vars == 3.1:
        print("Player has used Slash Attack")
        print("Monster[1] has taken 3.1 Hearts of DMG")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(MonsterHealth)
    
    elif vars == 5:
        print("Player has used Slam Attack")
        print("Monster[1] has taken 5 Hearts of DMG")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(MonsterHealth)
```

Comment: what is the initial definition of `Monster_One_Health`?

Comment: `Move_Chooser` is a list. If you want to pick one element at random, use `random.choice`.

Comment: Also, `if vars == 2.5` makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not using correctly, `random.sample`. Because you need just one element use the following:

```
Move_Chooser = random.choice(vars)
```

`random.choice` will give you one random element from a list. On the other hand, `random.sample` will return a list, and that's probably you are getting that error.

One suggestion for you is to use another name instead of `vars` since this is a python built-in function ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)).

Comment: I'd suggest you (as you already have a good answer) inform to avoid using `vars` as it's a python method

Comment: @azro, I agree with you. I just added that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Move_Chooser` is a type of `list`.
You can't operate the operator `-` for list and int as the error message states, next time please include all of your code so we don't need to "guess" your code, even though this time it was obvious.